# Regex remove first empty line

Tags: regex, empty-list

In a string like

```
z


h
```

I want to remove all empty values with the regex `[\r\n]+$`
You can see the [example](https://regex101.com/r/H5XDbh/1)

There is still remaning an empty line on top after the substitution, presumably line 3, according to Match Information section in the example above
Any suggestions on how to have this empty value matched as well
Thanks

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Please, give sample text and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all line breaks from the start of the string first.

The `/[\r\n]+$/mg` will remove all line breaks, but it stops before the last end of line char of a line break char streak, so all the initial empty lines but the last are removed.

So, in a PCRE (as well as .NET, Java, Python `re`, Ruby) pattern, you may use

```
\A[\r\n]+|[\r\n]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zBWVim/1), use it with multiline and global flag in the regex101 tester.

**Details**

- `\A[\r\n]+` - start of string and the 1+ CR or/and LF symbols, as many as possible
- `|`  - or
- `[\r\n]+$` - 1+ CR/LF symbols, as many as possible, followed with a line break or end of string.

Comment: Thanks again, I was almost there. I was trying the same thing, but with `^`, instead, as in  `^[\r\n]+|[\r\n]+$`. Even though `^` is Start of String, like `\A`, I can see now, that they are different, as they gave different results in this case. Thanks

Comment: @fionpo You use `m` modifier, it makes `^` match the start of string, or the position after a line break char. And `$` matches end of a line, not just the end of string then. `\A` always matches the start of string only. In the most recent JS engines that are ECMAScript 2018 compliant, `\A` is still not supported, but it can be emulated as `(?<![^])^`.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: Done @Wiktor Stribiżew